# Phonegap 3 + Sencha Touch 2.3.1 + Photo Image Gallery

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I'm taking photos with sencha and adding them to a List througth a store.
I take photos at full resolution (because I have to upload them after) and show them with a TPL like this:

```
<img src="{value}" width='120' height='120' />
```

And the photo code:

```
var cameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(successCallback, failCallback, cameraOptions);
```

And when I update the list with the image it became **SLOWLY.**, the app starts to crash when I take the 3rd picture...

I've already tested if I show only the title of each photo in the list and it works perfectly, I think that the problem is with the resize in the img tag for each big photo...

Is there any way to create a thumbnail from the photo that I had taken to show that in the list? or how can I fix this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Images in Sencha Touch List make my apps slow too

Comment: Are you on iOS or Android? iOS has been noted to have memory issues if the quality is set above 50. Something you could also try is setting a target width and height. The way you have it now those images are huge, setting those values might help it.

Comment: Yeah but I need them at full resolution, thats the idea of the app, but I need to show them as a list of previews too... when I show the list of the preview with size x,x with 4 or 5 images the app crash!:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it by creating a thumbnail attribute in the image model that contain a base64 string representation of the image resized (the thumbnail) using this code:

```
 var PREVIEW_WIDTH = 120;  
 var PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 120;  

 var img = new Image();  
 img.src = imageUri;  

 img.onload = function ()  
 {  
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");  
   canvas.width = PREVIEW_WIDTH;  
   canvas.height = PREVIEW_HEIGHT;  

   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT);  

   var thumbnail = canvas.toDataURL("image/" + _formatManager.getString());  
   // thumbnail contain the base64 resized image
 };
```

[Source](http://www.makingiants.com/2014/01/uri-to-base64-in-phonegap-and-sencha.html)